# UndoManager in NSResponder subclass (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, nsundomanager

I am trying to implement undo/redo in my model. So I made my model class a subclass of `NSResponder`, and then implemented the following:

**note**: this code is edited based on more research after comments

```
func setAnnotations(_ newAnnotations: [Annotation]) {
    let currentAnnotations = self.annotations

    self.undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: { (selfTarget) in
        selfTarget.setAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
    })

    self.annotations = newAnnotations
}
```

`Annotation` is a struct.

The code inside the closure never gets executed. Initially I noticed that `undoManager` is `nil`, but then I found this snippet:

```
private let _undoManager = UndoManager()
override var undoManager: UndoManager {
   return _undoManager
}
```

Now `undoManager` is no longer nil, but the code inside the closure still doesn't get executed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the closure never gets executed". The closure is not _supposed_ to be executed. It's just a closure that you hand to the undo manager for storage. It is called _when you undo_.

Comment: What I meant is, it is not executed when I undo - nothing gets undone.

Comment: "nothing gets undone" But that is not the same as "the closure never gets executed". The only way to know if the closure is executed is put a breakpoint or log a `print`. As for nothing getting undone, I'm not surprised, as your code makes no sense at all. You have a parameter `newAnnotations` which never gets used. The line `self.annotations = annotations` is insane, because the only `annotations` anywhere in sight is `self.annotations`, so you are just setting `self.annotations` to itself.

Comment: You are correct - I have updated the code, hope this is more clear. BTW, I found if I move this to a ViewController, it will work, so I may just do that and access the model from there. Still like to know why it doesn't work in an `NSResponder` subclass.

Comment: I did that following Apple's docs: "The most important code supporting undo should be in your model layer. Each model object in your application should be able to register undo invocations for all primitive methods that change the object." Maybe that is no longer true (?).

Comment: Ok, never mind my nonsense about the responder chain; I implemented your code (as far as you've shown it) and there's no problem. So the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Is the object, the subclass of `NSResponder`, in the responder chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce any issue now that you've made your undo register code make sense. Here is the *entire* code of a test app (I don't know what an Annotation is so I just used String):

```
import Cocoa
class MyResponder : NSResponder {
    private let _undoManager = UndoManager()
    override var undoManager: UndoManager {
        return _undoManager
    }
    typealias Annotation = String
    var annotations = ["hello"]
    func setAnnotations(_ newAnnotations: [Annotation]) {
        let currentAnnotations = self.annotations
        self.undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: { (selfTarget) in
            selfTarget.setAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
        })
        self.annotations = newAnnotations
    }
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let myResponder = MyResponder()
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print(self.myResponder.annotations)
        self.myResponder.setAnnotations(["howdy"])
        print(self.myResponder.annotations)
        self.myResponder.undoManager.undo()
        print(self.myResponder.annotations)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
["hello"]
["howdy"]
["hello"]
```

So Undo is working perfectly. If that's not happening for you, perhaps you are mismanaging your "model class" in some way.

---

By the way, a more correct to write your registration closure is this:

```
    self.undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: {
        [currentAnnotations = self.annotations] (selfTarget) in
        selfTarget.setAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
    })
```

This ensures that `self.annotations` is not captured prematurely.

Comment: Maybe I am mismanaging my model, I will have to look into that. Basically, my model class controls the 'state' of my app. If a user adds an 'annotation', it will passed on from a view controller to the model. I made it a separate class, so I would be available to various view controllers. I do notice you call 'undo()', so that must be triggered somehow. BTW, another view controller controls an `NSTextView`, maybe that one "scoops up" the undo before it reaches my model, even though the annotation was added after editing the text?

Comment: "I do notice you call 'undo()', so that must be triggered somehow" That is what I said in my very first comment. Undo doesn't happen by itself; it's something you do. You then assured me you were doing it. — Look, I know only what you've put in your question. The stuff in your comment above makes no sense to me. If you want to ask a question about that, with details, that would be great. I've answered the question _you actually asked_. You asserted that your undo code wasn't being called ("the code inside the closure still doesn't get executed"). I proved that it does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the undo doesn't happen by itself. I falsely assumed that it would, as long as you use a subclass of `NSResponder`. Good to know that the undo code by itself is working.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you imagine would trigger undo if not some user action, such as choosing Undo from the Edit menu. Is it supposed to happen just because the user has a sudden feeling of regret? :) If your question is why choosing Undo from the Edit menu doesn't trigger your undo, okay, that's yet _another_ thing you might want to ask about! But again, it wasn't in _this_ question.

Comment: Of course via de Undo/Redo menu ;) But my false assumption was that as a subclass of `NSResponder` eventually the undo command will reach it. And know I know it doesn't if it's not in the responder chain.

Comment: Yes, which I also said in a comment (later deleted). But that has nothing to do with Undo per se. It has to do with how menus work! — And please don't say "of course". Look back over your question and think about how little essential info you actually gave. You never said _anything_ about any menu! Your questions, and your comments too for that matter, are very poorly phrased. We have only words, so you must be clear and complete about what you are doing and what is going wrong.